# Sum of vector spaces - verifying answer

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the $\mathbb{R}$ vector space P($\mathbb{R}$) of polynomial functions over $\mathbb{R}$. Consider the subspaces V, W of P($\mathbb{R}$) defined by V = {*a*+ *bx* + *bx$^2$*: *a*, *b* $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$} and W = {*a*+ *bx*: *a*, *b* $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$}. Then we have that V + W is equal to:

I selected the answer: {2*a*+ 2*bx* + *bx$^2$*: *a*, *b* $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$} but apparently the answer is {*a* + *bx* + *cx$^2$*: *a*, *b* $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$}

Please explain where I went wrong. It turns out the answers were misaligned in the answers so I've corrected what the "correct" answer is meant to be

Comment: A minor point is that with the apparent answer of "{*a* + *bx* + *cx$^2$*: *a*, *b* $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$}", it should technically include "*c* $\in \mathbb{R}$".

Answer (score 1):

You want to know which polynomials $p(x)$ can be written as a sum of polynomials $a+bx+bx^2$ and $c+dx$. Thus
$$p(x)=(a+c)+x(b+d)+bx^2.$$
But we can assign values to $a,b,c,d$ to produce any polynomial of degree $\leq 2$. So the sum is actually $P_2(\Bbb{R})$.

Comment: Thanks. The number and the answers in the practice test answers were incorrectly aligned (fixed above) so your answer makes so much more sense now. Probably not helpful that the professor used the same letters to define both vector spaces  :)

Comment: The sum comprises all polynomials of degree $2$ or lower, but this space is not $P(\mathbb R)$, so your last sentence needs editing.

Comment: @L.ABrudvik-Lindner Using the same letters for both vector spaces was almost certainly intentional.  First, accords with standard practice (don’t introduce new variables that don’t serve a notational purpose).  And it also tests the student’s comprehension: your question was  based on a very very common type of error.